# How to run python script from command line

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python and I created a series of code but I don't know how to run them in the command line. I know the F5 stands for run in Shell, but how can I run my program in the command line?

Comment: Use __python yourfile.py__ and press __enter__

Comment: Check [Getting started with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/getting-started-with-python-language)

Comment: " F5 stands for run in Shell" in what? what are you using to run your python script? what have you researched so far?

Answer (score 0):

First you must run command prompt from the directory in which python is installed.
Open command prompt.
Change directory to where the python program is
For example:

```
c:> cd c:/python27
```

It returns something like:

```
C:/python27>
```

Then type:

```
python programe_name.py
```

That will run your program called **program_name.py**

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for  your advice, I'll try

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the directory where your `.py` file is. Say, if it's on your desktop, you would `cd desktop`

Then, from your desktop, run (on your command line): `python program_name.py`

You will either see your desired output, or Traceback errors, from which you can debug.